# What should I do with these emails?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, steganography

I've been sent a bunch of very odd emails recently, starting on Monday and sent daily until last Thursday. I'm not 100% sure what they mean or why I am being sent them, but perhaps you could help me.

Every email is sent from someone called '*advice@email-help.com*' and the subject is always '*Advice for emails*'. However, all the emails seem to be gibberish! They include a time, and some random word and thats it!

I've transcribed them below, in the order I received them. Perhaps you could figure out the advice that I am being sent?

---

Monday

> 6:38 PRELUSIVE
> 1:38 ENNOBLES
> 3:08 *S*PELLING
> 6:38 BACKWARD
> 3:52 SAFEGUA*R*D
> 9:23 DEFL*E*CTED

Tuesday

> 6:15 AR*T*ICGUSTS
> 1:38 EXAMINABLE
> 6:38 PRELEC*T*FUL
> 6:23 CABBAGE

Wednesday

> 3:52 AGEDFIND
> 9:53 IN*E*XCITABLE
> 1:53 F*L*AGGED
> 9:15 CHILDIS*H*BOYS

Thursday

> 7:15 FLOWERED
> 6:38 DIALOGED
> 7:53 UNGIF*T*ED
> 1:38 XXX*X*XXXX

---

After that, the emails stopped. I should probably ignore them, but they've been stuck in my mind.

### What should I do with these emails?

Comment: The Gerbil hath posted another puzzle!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The italicised letters

> spell XTH LETTERS backwards.

Using that,

> we can index into each word by the three digits of the time to get a message:
>  SEVEN SEG / ACDFG / ADEFG / ACE / ABCEFG / ABEFG / BCEFG / ABCDEF / EG / ADEFG

Interpreting these

> [image]
>  as seven-segment display letters, they spell out `SEMAPHORE`.

And this gives the advice:

> interpreting the given times as semaphore, we get the answer `ALWAYS FLAG YOUR MAIL`.

Comment: Ah... I mis-spaced the first few as rot13('FRIRAF R.T.' naq gura gevrq gb genafyngr nyy gur yrggref nf zhfvpny abgrf) - I've just spent the last few minutes singing for no reason! Well done :) +1

Comment: How do you interpret the times as semaphore?

Comment: @bobble if you take the times and look at where the hands of a clock would point